# SQL Self Join / Sub Query

Tags: mysql, subquery, self-join

I got stuck in the below query, Tables as follows.
**wktest**(Store, dt, sale)
**Cal** (dt, fin_yr, wk)

Note: wktest is a sale table which has last year & current year, I want to get result of Last year's sale and current year's sale by week with following key

Current year's WK number + weekday = Last year's WK number + weekday

```
select w.Store,c.Fin_Yr ,c.Wk, sum(w.sale)
        from wktest w
        join cal c on w.dt = c.dt
        where
        concat(c.wk,weekday(w.dt)) = 
        
        (select concat(cal.wk,weekday(wktest.dt)) from cal join wktest on cal.dt = wktest.dt where wktest.dt between '2019-04-01' and '2020-03-31')
        
        group by w.Store,c.Fin_Yr ,c.Wk;
```

Sharing Sample tables & expected output
[image]

Comment: Please share sample data data insert scripts with create table script. Also, share the output data you are expecting from sample data.

Comment: You tell "by week with following key", but the key granularity is a day, not a week.

Comment: @Akina Thanks, Trying to concat week number & weekday to find common inbetween 2 years

Comment: @AmitVerma, Thanks, added sample tables & expected output.

Comment: *Sharing Sample tables & expected output* I see simple summarizing per week. And I cannot understand how the weekday may affect on - I'd simply ignore it.

Comment: @Akina, I want to compare only 3 days (operational days) of current year with same weekdays of past year

Comment: *I want to compare only 3 days (operational days) of current year with same weekdays of past year* I.e. if for FY20 there are rows for Mon,Wed, Fri and for FY22 - Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, then you want to summarize only 2 rows (Mon, Wed) from each year, is it?

Comment: Does `cal` table can be ignored? all its data can be calculated from `wktest.dt` value.

Comment: thanks for your reply... I want to compate Tue, Thu, Sat of FY22 with Same days of FY20, mistakenly highlighted wrong cells, cal table has week numbers which I would need for reporting as a filter

Comment: *I.e. if for FY20 there are rows for Mon,Wed, Fri and for FY22 - Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, then you want to summarize only 2 rows (Mon, Wed) from each year, is it?* Please tell either "yes" or "no", if no then specify weekdays list for to summarize for each year and explain why so. *Does cal table can be ignored?* Please answer "yes" or "no".

Comment: Both year Mon, Thu, Sat - since both year weekdays are same for week 10; no 'cal' table can't ne ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test, maybe this query is safe for you?

```
SELECT wk, SUM(FY20.sale) FY20_sale, SUM(FY22.sale) FY22_sale
FROM ( SELECT dt, cal.wk, wktest.sale
       FROM wktest
       JOIN cal USING (dt)
       WHERE cal.fin_yr = 'FY20' ) FY20
JOIN ( SELECT dt, cal.wk, wktest.sale
       FROM wktest
       JOIN cal USING (dt)
       WHERE cal.fin_yr = 'FY22' ) FY22 USING (wk)
WHERE WEEKDAY(FY20.dt) = WEEKDAY(FY22.dt)
GROUP BY wk
```

The query assimes that `dt` column values are unique in each separate table.